# Jhipster delivery as jar packaging : I don't manage to access login page

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I just changed the output delivery as jar instead of war inside the pom.xml. But now, I've don't manage to load the login page. Not displayed. Cf. screenshot.
What should I do to make "One file delivery" ?

Thanks

[Error loading login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8IiC.jpg)

Comment: Which version? Post your .yo-rc.json file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved.

In fact, it is not needed to change to jar output. The generated war is already executable. (like jar command : java -jar your.war).
Maven spring boot plugin outputs 2 war files : xxx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war and xxx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.original. The former contains tomcat embedd librairies (and more differences) and then it is the executable one. The latter contains old fashion war file : to be put into an external servlet container.

Thanks.